# Advantages of BooleanProperty in GAE NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Does using property type BooleanProperty give us any performance advantage(like faster query response or anything else) compared to using another property type. The property is used as a flag(only two possible values)

I use GAE with Python

Example 1:

```
class H(ndb.Model): 
    p = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

Example 2:

```
class H(ndb.Model): 
    p = ndb.IntegerProperty() # with possible values as 0 or 1
```

Is example 1 approach better in terms of performance or storage

I know, by convention, it is appropriate to use example 1 approach but i am curious to know if we get any benefits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Boolean takes less space than an Integer.

You have to have millions of records, however, to notice any difference.

Comment: Thanks Andrei.. do you think there would an improvement wrt query performance too..

Comment: I don't think there would be any noticeable difference.

Comment: Thanks Andrei.. I still feel they could have given query performance advantage to property types which can have only two possible values..